# Why is the ng-show directive not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show

This is the form.

```
    <div class="row" ng-controller="contactsCtrl">

<form ng-show="addFormShow">
    <h3>Add Contact</h3>
    <!-- Add form -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Name:
                <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Contact Name" required />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Email:
                <input type="text" ng-model="email" placeholder="Contact Email" required />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Company:
                <input type="text" ng-model="company" placeholder="Company Name" required />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Work Phone:
                <input type="text" ng-model="work_phone" placeholder="Work Phone" required />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Mobile Phone:
                <input type="text" ng-model="mobile_phone" placeholder="Mobile Phone" required />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Home Phone:
                <input type="text" ng-model="home_phone" placeholder="Home Phone" required />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Street Address:
                <input type="text" ng-model="street_address" placeholder="Street Address" required />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>City:
                <input type="text" ng-model="city" placeholder="City" required />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>State:
                <input type="text" ng-model="state" placeholder="State" required />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Zip Code:
                <input type="text" ng-model="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" required />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" class="button" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="large-10 columns">
    <h3>Your Contacts (3)</h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="200px">Name</th>
                <th width="200px">Company</th>
                <th width="25%">Email</th>
                <th width="25%">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
                <td><a href="#">{{contact.name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{contact.company}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                <td><a class="button tiny" ng-click="showEditForm(contact)">Edit</a>
                    <a class="button tiny alert" ng-click="removeContact(contact)">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="small-12 large-2 columns">
    <a class="button large" ng-click="showAddForm()">+</a>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the controller.

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('myContacts.contacts', ['ngRoute','firebase'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/contacts', {
    templateUrl: 'contacts/contacts.html',
    controller: 'contactsCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('contactsCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', function($scope,$firebaseArray) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://mycontacts-1bb2d.firebaseio.com/contacts');

    $scope.contacts = $firebaseArray(ref);
    $scope.showAddForm = function(){
        $scope.addFormShow = true;
    }
}]);
```

This is pretty simple code. Its supposed to show the form when the user clicks on the '+' button. But I cant figure out why the ng-show directive is not working.

Comment: You might have some other Issue Your code is working fine check this plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/lftU1bPhL2kyWibjZQX6?p=preview

Comment: I suggest you to replace that function (and its call) by a simple negation expression in your `ng-click`, just as a general improvement (even though it's not related to your problem).

For example: `<a ng-click="addFormShow  = !addFormShow">`

Of course, if your only intention is to show the form and not hide it, you can just use `addFormShow = true` inside the `ng-click`.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with your code, check if you have properly added ng-controller in your code.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('ReqWebApp', [])

myApp.controller('contactsCtrl', function contactsCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.showAddForm = function(){
    $scope.addFormShow = true;
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ReqWebApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Request</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="contactsCtrl">
    <form ng-show="addFormShow">
<h3>Add Contact</h3>
<!-- Add form -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <label>Name:
            <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Contact Name" required />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <label>Email:
            <input type="text" ng-model="email" placeholder="Contact Email" required />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" class="button" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<div class="small-12 large-2 columns">
    <a class="button large" ng-click="showAddForm()">+</a>
</div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should be asking this question to check the controller is incuded or not in the comment section. This should be clear first rather that posting it as an answer,

Comment: Thanx for the advice but I have added the controller properly. If I post my whole code it will be too lengthy. I omitted some of the code as it deals with the firebase but I thought this much should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

The code works fine for me. I think you might have done some small error in adding controller. Refer the code below

```
<html ng-app='FormApp'>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller='contactsCtrl'>
 <form ng-show="addFormShow">
    <h3>Add Contact</h3>
    <!-- Add form -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Contact Name" required />
    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label>Email:
        <input type="text" ng-model="email" placeholder="Contact Email" required />
    </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" class="button" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="small-12 large-2 columns">
    <a class="button large" ng-click="showAddForm()">+</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    angular.module('FormApp', []).controller('contactsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.showAddForm = function() {
            $scope.addFormShow = true;
        }
    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added the controller. I just omitted some code because it deals with firebase which is not relevant to my problem. Check the updated code.

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console when you click the "+"?

Comment: No but the form is showing even before I click on the '+' button.

Comment: I am not familiar with firebase but I think it is because of firebase connection issue, it is showing a connection fail error for. Make sure the database link is valid

Comment: Ok. I'll let you know when I figure out whats wrong.